# Close firefox after loading home page via command line

Tags: firefox, command-line

Is there a way to start firefox from command line with specific homepage and wait til homepage is loaded? After loading homepage just quit firefox?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the -url flag 

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

To wait for the homepage to be loaded there is is different approach. What's your OS ?

Comment: Windows7 is my operating system